# What is the difference between 'warning area' and 'ADIZ'? Are they overlapped with each other?

Tags: airspace

On FAR AIM, definition of **warning area** is

> Airspace of defined dimensions,
>   extending from three nautical miles outward from the
>   coast of the U.S, that contains activity that may be
>   hazardous to nonparticipating aircraft

And on Wikipedia, definition of **ADIZ** is

> Airspace over land or water in which the identification, location, and control of civil aircraft is performed in the interest of national security.

I was confused because the definition of these two airspace is similar with each other. And I thought that those area could be overlapped with each other. Could anyone explain the difference, or at least an example chart that contains this two areas?

And if an aircraft tried to fly to the U.S territory from the sea, which area does the aircraft encounter first : 'warning area' or 'ADIZ'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a [good explanation of Warning areas (and lots of other areas) in the answer to this question.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20877/what-are-some-examples-of-warning-areas-and-restricted-areas)

ADIZ is effectively the controlled area that *surrounds* the US/CANADA border. The picture from the [wiki article shows it quite well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Defense_Identification_Zone_(North_America))

[image]

The ADIZ was created to have an area to identify inbound, out of country, aircraft. [As per the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/us_restrictions/airspace/)

> All aircraft entering U.S. domestic airspace from points outside must
>   provide for identification prior to entry or exit. **ADIZs have been
>   established to assist in early identification of aircraft in the
>   vicinity of international U.S. airspace boundaries** (AIM Section 6,
>   5-6-1)

As far as I know there are no ADIZ areas internal to the country, although warning areas may be anywhere within the nations jurisdiction. I see no reason they could not overlap each other either.

Comment: To clarify your statement, warning areas exist outside US airspace (starting 3 NM off the coast.) They work similar to Restricted airspace, but because it isn't US airspace the US can't restrict air traffic. They just warn you that there is hazardous activity. There's a lot of air-to-air weapons testing in the Warning areas over the Gulf of Mexico near Eglin AFB, FL.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the ADIZ also exists along the US/Mexico land border but is infinitesimally thick?

Comment: @pericynthion  Not exactly. The ADIZ 'near side' is displayed on the charts as a line. The line is the point where you enter/exit US airspace. In coastal areas, the ADIZ extends out to the extent of the US FIR which is the area under US air traffic control. At the Mexican border the line follows the border, and the the other side is Mexican airspace. The US can't define/control any airspace over Mexico, but that doesn't mean they (both US and Mexico) aren't watching. And with a flight plan, you'll get a handoff from/to the Mexican ATC.